# Arrays to binary files and vice versa

Tags: c++, arrays, binaryfiles

I was trying to write an array of ints to a binary file and then read the just written file and write it in another array (of the same size of the first), but i don't understand why the second array contains the correct numbers only until 25 (its 26th element, since numbers i wrote in the first start from 0).

A very weird thing i noticed, is that if i replace 'x[i] = i;' with 'x[i] = i * 3;' in the first for cycle in main, i obtain the correct numbers printed until 279 instead of 25 (and 25*3 != 279).

How could I write/read binary files to/from raw arrays in C++?

main.cpp:

```
#include "arrays_binary_files.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x[1000];
    //#if 0
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i != sizeof x / sizeof * x; ++i)
        x[i] = i;
    //#endif
    int y[sizeof x / sizeof *x];

    std::cout << "scrivo x su x.bin? [invio per continuare] _";//write?
    (void)getchar();
    std::cout << "\nscrivo x su x.bin...";//writing...
    arrToBinFile(x, sizeof x / sizeof * x, "x.bin");
    std::cout << "\nscritto x su x.bin";//written!

    std::cout << "\n\nscrivo x.bin su y? [invio per continuare] _";//read?
    (void)getchar();
    std::cout << "scrivo x.bin su y...";//reading...
    binFileToArr("x.bin", y, sizeof y / sizeof * x);
    std::cout << "\nscritto x.bin su y";//read!

    std::cout << "\n\nvisualizzo y? [invio per continuare] _";//show?
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i != sizeof y / sizeof * y; ++i) {
        std::cout << '\n' << y[i];//stampa bene solo fino a 25
        (void)getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

arrays_binary_files.hpp:

```
#ifndef arrays_binary_files_hpp_included
#define arrays_binary_files_hpp_included
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

//namespace {
/*
* gives internal linkage (like specifying static for everything), so that each 
* function is "local" in each translation unit which is pasted in by #include
*/

//i tried to inline in order to debug using breakpoints, but i didn't understand the same where the bug is
inline char arrToBinFile(const int inputArray[], const size_t inputArrayLength, const std::string& fileName) {
    std::ofstream outputData;
    outputData.open(fileName);
    if (outputData) {
        outputData.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(inputArray), sizeof(int) * inputArrayLength);
        outputData.close();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        outputData.close();
        return -1;
    }
}

//i tried to inline to debug using breakpoints, but i didn't understand the same where the bug is
inline char binFileToArr(const std::string& fileName, int outputArray[], const size_t outputArrayLength) {
    std::ifstream inputData;
    inputData.open(fileName);
    if (inputData /*&& std::filesystem::file_size(fileName) <= outputArrayLength*/) {
        inputData.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(outputArray), sizeof(int) * outputArrayLength);
        inputData.close();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        inputData.close();
        return -1;
    }
}
//}
#endif
```

screenshot of the console in case of leaving the main function in main.cpp as it is:
[image: screenshot_of_the_console_1]

screenshot of the console in case of replacing 'x[i] = i;' with 'x[i] = i * 3;' in the main function in main.cpp:
[image: screenshot_of_the_console_2]

Comment: You must be using a very weird operating system called "Microsoft Windows" which insists on interpreting octet 26, CTRL-Z, as an artificial end of file marker, and hilarity ensues. This does not happen on Linux.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik In your opinion what could I do to circumvent this problem, apart move on Linux XD?

Comment: Make it `outputData.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);`, and similarly with `inputData`. You are not actually creating a binary file, but a text file.